# Managing stock images vs my own images

Tags: stock-photography

I do a lot of web development and blogging and I tend to use a fair bit of creative commons stock imagery. I've got quite a big collection of  images but I'm concerned about storing and organizing these away from my own photos and also keeping the metadata intact for them so I can reference the authors easily. Any tips for this situation? I use Adobe Lightroom.

Comment: You can manage them in a separate catalog.

Comment: The Copyright field in the image meta data is designed for this, if you took the picture, it's your name in the copyright, if someone else did, then it should be their name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my point of view, it's not only important that you yourself know the license, but also that you have a proof of it. One day you may receive a letter from a copyright lawyer claiming that you use these images in an illegal way.

My own practice: For every image / song / video that I download I also save the web page with the license statement as PDF and take care that their filenames are the same. This PDF file is always copied together with the image / song / video, for example into my thematic collection of my own media.

If somebody then questions the license or I don't remember the download source anymore: It's all in the PDF.

This save-as-PDF solution is part of the print dialog box on Mac OSX or Linux. On Windows it can be installed as a print driver, for example with the free [doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com).